# Mixing CSS Grid named areas with rows and columns numbers isn't working for me

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm starting to deal with CSS Grids now and I'm trying to understand the behavior of mixing named grid areas with the syntax `grid-area: 1/3/3/5`.

In the code below, for what I understand I am creating 2 columns (`grid-template-columns: 25% 75%`) and dividing it into 5 "pieces" (`"hd hd hd hd hd"`, etc.)

I know that for the `#four` element I could just set `grid-area: ft`. 
But why doesn't `grid-area: 3/1/3/2` work the same way?
I thougt that by using `2` in `grid-area: 3/1/3/2` (last column = 2), the element would take up the two columns I created with `grid-template-columns: 25% 75%`.

Instead, it takes up only a small portion of the last row. I need to use `6` (why 6?) to make it take up the whole row.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 75%;
  grid-template-rows: 150px 350px 80px;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "hd hd hd hd hd"
    "sb main main main main"
    "ft ft ft ft ft";
}

#one{
  grid-area: hd;
}

#two{
  grid-area: sb;
}

#three{
  grid-area: main;
}

#four{
  grid-area: 3/1/3/6;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" id="one">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box" id="two">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box" id="three">Box 3</div>
  <div class="box" id="four">Box 4</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: *I could just set grid-area: ft. But why doesn't grid-area: 3/1/3/2 work the same way?* Because this `grid-area: 3/1/3/2` means start at column 1 and row 3 end at row 3 and column 2 you're basically telling the element to sit within  the first column of the third row. think of the number as the lines between the columns not the actual columns. you need 6 because you defined 5 columns and if we count from the first line being the outer left edge 1 we'll have 6 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the code below, for what I understand I am creating 2 columns (grid-template-columns: 25% 75%) and dividing it into 5 "pieces" ("hd hd hd hd hd", etc.)

You are creating 5 columns where the first two are equal to `25%` and `75%` while the last 3 are empty.

In your case using `grid-area: 3/1/3/2` or `grid-area: 3/1/3/6` will give you the same *visual* result since you have 3 empty columns but you can notice a difference if you add some gaps:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 21% 75%;
  grid-gap:1%;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "hd hd hd hd hd"
    "sb main main main main"
    "ft ft ft ft ft";
  margin:5px;
  border:1px solid;
}

#one{
  grid-area: hd;
}

#two{
  grid-area: sb;
}

#three{
  grid-area: main;
}

#four{
  grid-area: 3/1/3/6;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box" id="one">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box" id="two">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box" id="three">Box 3</div>
  <div class="box" id="four">Box 4</div>  
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="box" id="one">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box" id="two">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box" id="three">Box 3</div>
  <div class="box" id="four" style="grid-area: 3/1/3/3;">Box 4</div>  
</div>
```

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#explicit-grids):

> The size of the explicit grid is determined **by the larger** of the number of rows/columns defined by `grid-template-areas` and the number of rows/columns sized by `grid-template-rows`/`grid-template-columns`. Any rows/columns defined by `grid-template-areas` but not sized by `grid-template-rows`/`grid-template-columns` take their size from the `grid-auto-rows`/`grid-auto-columns` properties

By default `grid-auto-columns` is set to `auto` and by setting `25% 75%` you already covered all the space available thus you will have 3 empty columns.